# android - Upload failed: You need to use a different version code for your APK

Tags: android, updates

Tell me sir please what I do always same message help please update fail

Comment: go through this url you will get how to set version code ans name for your app https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html

Comment: delete from artifact library.

Answer (score 7):

> If you have uploaded you android apk previously on play store then next time 
>   whenever you upload a new built you need to change your version code
>   and version name (every time you upload a new built).

```
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"
```

[image]